# Banno External Plugin S3 Hosting Question

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am developing 2 plugins for Banno and have a hosting question.

My client will be hosting the plugins on S3. Can I use 1 bucket for both plugins or will they each need a bucket?

Thank you.

I haven't uploaded anything to S3 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have material *specific* to Amazon Web Services (e.g., S3) but here's some general guidance which may be helpful.

No matter what, you'll need to make sure that your plugin's content is hosted by your public-facing web server. This means your web server must be accessible via the internet and cannot require the user to be on a specific network or VPN.

See these resources for more info:

- [Plugin Framework / Architecture / Hosting](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/hosting/)
- [Plugin Framework / Guides/ Designing and Developing Plugins](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/)

The gist is that how you build your plugin's web service is at your discretion.

- Whether you have separate S3 buckets or a single S3 bucket, that's up to you to decide what's best for your plugin.